# I can't use javascript "for in" syntax in blueimp/JavaScript-Templates

Tags: javascript, templates, blueimp

I'm writing a javascript template using blueimp-tmpl,when I using code below the result is right:

```
<script type="text/x-tmpl" id="tmpl-posts">
{% for (var i=0;i<o.content.length;i++) {
    var item=o.content[i];
%}
<tr>

    <td><a href="postDetail.html?id={%=item.id%}">{%=item.title%}</a></td>
    <td>{%=item.posterNickName%}</td>
    <td>{%=item.createTime%}</td>
    <td>{%=item.lastUpdateTime%}</td>
    <td>{%=item.replyCount%}</td>

    {% if(item.posterId==1&&!item.locked){ %}
        <td><a href="updatePost.html?id={%=item.id%}">修改</a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:del('{%=item.id%}')">删除</a></td>
    {% }else{ %}
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    {% } %}

</tr>
{% } %}
</script>
```

but when I change the for loop to "for in", the result is empty,and the chrome-devtools report a error, then I refresh the page,the error disappear and the result is still empty.

```
<script type="text/x-tmpl" id="tmpl-posts">
{% for (var item in o.content){ %}
<tr>

    <td><a href="postDetail.html?id={%=item.id%}">{%=item.title%}</a></td>
    <td>{%=item.posterNickName%}</td>
    <td>{%=item.createTime%}</td>
    <td>{%=item.lastUpdateTime%}</td>
    <td>{%=item.replyCount%}</td>

    {% if(item.posterId==1&&!item.locked){ %}
        <td><a href="updatePost.html?id={%=item.id%}">修改</a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:del('{%=item.id%}')">删除</a></td>
    {% }else{ %}
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    {% } %}

</tr>
{% } %}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why either but you can do it this way.
Modify this line:

```
{% for (var item in o.content){ %}
```

to:

```
{% for (var i=0, item; o.content[i]; i++){ %}
```